# How to add a prefix to each value in a dictionary, using a loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, prefix

I've been given the following dictionary:

```
phonebook = {'Tom': '0545345345367',
             'John': '0764345323434',
             'Sandy': '0235452342465',
             'Ewan': '0656875345234',
             'Andy': '0673423123454',
             'Rebecca': '0656875345234',
             'Vicky': '0456740034344',
             'Gary': '0656875345234'}
```

And the problem asks me to add the prefix `'0044-'` before each phone number by using a for loop. I've tried to research it but everything I find seems far too complex for a problem like this.

Comment: So what you try before ?

Comment: I don't know where to begin really, it's more complicated than what i've been taught!

Comment: did you searched about this problem before you asking ? (i think you didn't)

Comment: I did, that's why in my question it says 'I've tried to research it but everything I find seems far too complex for a problem like this.'

Comment: follow http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=replace+values+in+dictionary+python you will find a couple related question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for k in phonebook:
    phonebook[k] = '0044-' + phonebook[k]
```

I dislike the "mutation in place while iterating" approach.

But in this particular case it's safe (no keys are inserted or deleted). Iterate over `phonebook.keys()` if you want to always be safe.

Comment: Almost - just mutate `phonebook` - not `new_numbers`... (it isn't stated the OP wants a new `dict`)

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for! But yes, I agree with Jon Clements, so I just mutated phonebook rather than making a new dictionary but thank you!

Comment: Edited with a warning.

Answer (score 7):

```
phonebook = {k: '0044-'+v for k,v in phonebook.items()}
```

Comment: Note that this will rebind the name `phonebook` - if the `dict` is being used elsewhere, the changes won't be present via any other references